# Build XML document from a oracle query in C#

Tags: c#, xml

Whats the best way of building xml document based on few oracle queries in C#

select orderID,qty,orderDate,deliveryDate from Orders

```
<orders>
   <order>
     <orderID>1</orderID>
     <qty>10</qty>
     <orderDate>22-Jan-2012</orderDate>
     <deliveryDate>25-Jan-2012</deliveryDate>


   </order> 
<order>
     <orderID>2</orderID>
     <qty>10</qty>
     <orderDate>22-Jan-2012</orderDate>
     <deliveryDate>25-Jan-2012</deliveryDate>


   </order> 
</orders>
```

Please advice

Comment: Your XML seems to contradict the question posed. Are you looking to turn a query to XML or the _result_ of your query to XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use XElement. 
Code Example:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    con.Open();
    using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select orderID,qty,orderDate,deliveryDate from Orders", con))
    {
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        XElement root = new XElement("Orders");
        while(reader.Read())
        {
            root.AddFirst(
                new XElement("Order", 
                from i in Enumerable.Range(0, reader.FieldCount)
                    select 
                        new XElement(reader.GetName(i), reader.GetValue(i))
                )
            );
        }
        root.Save(Console.Out);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this example: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301271

Except instead of SqlConnection & SqlDataAdapter, use [OracleConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracleconnection.aspx) & [OracleDataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracledataadapter%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the oracle query itself.

Please find the below link

https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1034099